# Is there a tool to visualise the task dependencies in a gulp file?

Tags: gulp, dependencies, visualization

We have some (probably needlessly) complex gulp files and I can't find a tool that will show the dependencies in a some visual manner - even just a text output like npm does.

Eg given

```
gulp.task('something:else', ...
gulp.task('ts:compile', ['something:else'], function () {
gulp.task('copy:i18n', ...
gulp.task('test', ['ts:compile', 'copy:i18n'], ...
```

It will output something like

```
test
-> ts:compile
--> something:else
-> copy:i18n
```

or even better, some visual diagram/png/etc

Comment: `gulp --tasks`.

Comment: Thanks. That's somewhat useful. It only seems to display one level though - ie the dependencies of each task - ie it doesn't display the --> something:else. I tried using the --depth arg to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found these:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-task-graph-visualizer - it presents a text representation like the output in the question.

Better was this one:

https://github.com/pavlov99/gulp-graph-tasks - it creates a visual graph of the task dependencies and is exactly what I was looking for.